# python pandas select all NaN row and fill with previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` look like this,

```
pd.DataFrame([list(range(8))+[np.nan]*2, [np.nan]*len(range(10)), range(10), [np.nan]*2+list(range(8)), range(10)])
Out[31]: 
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
```

I want to select the row with all `NaN`, that is the second in this case and fill it with the previous row.

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
```

How to do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can do:

```py
mask = df.isna().all(axis=1)

df.loc[mask, :] = df.loc[mask.shift(-1).fillna(False), :].values
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
```

Comment: Was about to post something similar: `df[mask] = df.shift()[mask]` ;)

Comment: @gsamaras No, leave it. It's good to have multiple choices.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), like this:

```
# get the row with all NaNs
nan_row_index = data.isna().all(axis=1)

# fill the NaN row with the previous row's values using 'ffill'
df.loc[nan_row_index, :] = df.ffill()
```

Output (of `print(df)`):

```
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
1  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
2  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
3  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
4  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0  9.0
```